# Image Upload into Drive Using api and get back the url of image for android application

Tags: android, kotlin

i am working on android application which has requirement of image uploads.instead of posting into server directly,
I am trying to upload(post) image in Google drive Or Clouding and get back the URL of the image and store it in database for further requirement in the android application.

i have tried cloudinary but it didnt work out..now i'm trying using google drive(api)..
I followed some of the answers given by developers from stackoverflow..but the codes are in the format of integrating the google drive to application,my requirement is different..i dont want to show gmail names for upload.

if i click on upload Button then images will store into google drive and get the url and store it in Database